# format data using pandas.dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am new to pandas, I need some guidance. I have a dictionary and I wrote the code below to create a dataframe to write to excel sheet.

```
dict = { "name": "xyz",
         "desciption":"abc",
         "paths": ["a","b","c"]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

...............................................................

I have to create a dataframe and write it to excel. My excel should show data in the format:

```
name  description  paths
xyz   abc           a
                    b
                    c
```

but what i am actually getting is:

```
name  description  paths
xyz   abc           a
xyz   abc           b
xyz   abc           c
```

Comment: You could make it a MultiIndex and then save the MultiIndex to excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the duplicates of columns `name` and `desciption` and make them empty strings:

```
# keep only the first one, mark others as duplicates
dups = df.duplicated(["name", "desciption"], keep="first")

# put empty string to those places
df.loc[dups, ["name", "desciption"]] = ""
```

which gives

```
>>> df

  name desciption paths
0  xyz        abc     a
1                     b
2                     c
```

and you can write this frame to file.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

paths = ["a", "b", "c"]

d = {"name": ["xyz"] + [''] * (len(paths) - 1),
     "desciption": ["abc"] + [''] * (len(paths) - 1),
     "paths": paths
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

  name desciption paths
0  xyz        abc     a
1                     b
2                     c
```

You can get rid of index numbers via `df.to_excel(index=False)`.

Comment: Your solution is good but I can't modify the dict as it is getting populated by some other piece of code.